# PDF pages in wrong order

Tags: jspdf

I have this

```
        $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {  
            $('body').scrollTop(0);                 
            createPDF();  
        });  

        //create pdf  
        function createPDF() {  
            
            doc = new jsPDF({  
                     unit: 'px',  
                     format: 'a4'  
                 });
            
            
            const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width - 20;
            current_div = current_div1;     
            cache_width = current_div.width(); 
             cache_width = current_div.width(); 
                
            getCanvas(document.querySelector("#thediv1")).then(function (canvas) {  
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", wid = canvas.width, hgt = canvas.height) ;  
            
                var hratio = hgt/wid;
                
                const TheHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.width;                  
                const pdfHeight = TheHeight * hratio                    
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);                     
                doc.addPage(595, 842);
                
            }); 
        
            current_div = current_div2; 
            cache_width = current_div.width();
            getCanvas(document.querySelector("#thediv2")).then(function (canvas) {  
                    
                 var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", wid = canvas.width, hgt = canvas.height) ;  
                var hratio = hgt/wid;   
                
                const TheHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.width;                  
                const pdfHeight = TheHeight * hratio
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight); 
                doc.addPage(595, 842);
                 
            }); 
            current_div = current_div3;     
            cache_width = current_div.width();
        
            getCanvas(document.querySelector("#thediv3")).then(function (canvas) {  
                
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", wid = canvas.width, hgt = canvas.height) ;  
                var hratio = hgt/wid;
                
                
                const TheHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.width;                  
                const pdfHeight = TheHeight * hratio
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight); 
                doc.addPage(595, 842);                
            });
```

etc etc

```
            current_div = current_div14;    
            cache_width = current_div.width();
        
            getCanvas(document.querySelector("#thediv14")).then(function (canvas) {  
                
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", wid = canvas.width, hgt = canvas.height) ;  
                var hratio = hgt/wid;
                const TheHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.width;                  
                const pdfHeight = TheHeight * hratio
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight); 
                
                doc.addPage(595, 842);                      
                doc.autoPrint();
                window.open(doc.output('bloburl')); 
            }); 
        }  


        // create canvas object  
        function getCanvas(Link) {                  
            current_div.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');             
            return html2canvas(Link, {  
                imageTimeout: 2000,  
                removeContainer: true  
            });  
        }
```

I have two problems.

I am getting all the pages but not always in the right order. Why is that and what can I do about it?

Is there a way of stopping it from writing to the original page as the width is smaller than the original so it looks terrible. The original page needs to look the same as it did before clicking the print button

Thanks

Comment: The two pages that are coming out in the wrong order are the two that contain images by the look of it. They are coming out after they should do.

Comment: They lose the order because of the size of the pages. Asyncronous makes the lighter one go first

Answer (score 0):

I used Dompdf in the end. I was much easier